# Free or open source Diagram component for C#?

Tags: c#, user-interface, diagram, diagramming, uicomponents

Is there any [Diagramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wikipedia_article-creation-2.svg) component that is freely available for a C# project? If possible one that allows you to click and edit the diagram nodes.

Comment: Would you mind if the component was for .NET and not for C#?

Comment: No. As long as it works with a C# project, i.e. I don't want anything for ASP.NET!

Comment: Did you find any free or open source component that worked for you? I'm currently looking for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is [the beginning of one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx).

Answer (score -3):

Well I don't know if you are looking to model just some basic logic steps, or get really in depth and model classes and functions themselves. But, for most design work I do, and this include diagrams, I like to use [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/). It's free, and pretty powerful, though you do have to understand UML, but otherwise I think it is a great tool.

Comment: I wanted a C# component that I could build my own diagram editor around. Not an independent app.