# How do I start doing diagram development in c#

Tags: c#, graphics, diagram

I'd like to try to create a diagram making tool (something like entity-relation diagram you can create in SQL Server 2005, or class diagrams you can do in Microsoft Visual Studio)

Ie. I'd like to create boxes, put text in them, be able to edit this text and draw lines between boxes.

I never did this kind of programming before so I don't know where to start.

Do I use XAML or create a canvas and go into graphics programming?

I know there are some diagram tools out there but I'd really like to find out of these things by doing it myself.

Comment: A while back I tried to do something similar myself with logic diagrams and didn't get very far. I'm highly interested in your project and the answers you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendering engine you pick is somewhat arbitrary - you're going to have to do a lot of work no matter what framework you use.

Having implemented such a system in C# and WinForms, I can honestly say that's a bad route to go. Stick to WPF/Silverlight. Going with trends, write a Silverlight 4 app so you can deploy to desktops on multiple platforms.

I found that there are a lot of high-level decisions that you have to make that are even more important than which rendering engine you use. Some of these are:

- How much do you need to zoom and pan around?

  - Do you want continuous zoom so that you can do neat animations to the data?
  - Do you need to be able to pan with just the mouse?
  - How will you distinguish pan movements from dragging around boxes and handles?
  - Will you change the layout of content in the boxes dependent upon the current zoom level? or will you rely on font scaling?
- Do you need grouping? Once you get a few tables on the screen you will soon realize that being able to *hide some detail* is useful. Being able to group boxes and to show that group in iconic form as "meta" box allows the user to get rid of unwanted distractions.
- Do you need search? Again trying to combat the "too much on the screen" problem, it's good to have a search box that hides everything that doesn't match the search (gray out, hide, etc.)
- How will the user interact with the keyboard. Since your audience can include programmers, you're going to want to give a lot of thought to making all your diagrams editable with just the keyboard. This means things like handling focus intelligently along with which hot keys to use.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is [the basis of one on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx), with source and a tutorial. For WPF.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201248/free-or-open-source-diagram-component-for-c).

Comment: Wow that looks like 80% of any diagramming app, great link! +1

Answer (score 2):

WPF/XAML are a great place to start for something like this.  You'll want to study WPF in general, with a focus on custom controls (for tables) and drawing lines (for the relationships.)

Answer (score 1):

As Frank has pointed out - creating interactive graphics is big business.  Many companies have already been there, spent £millions perfecting it.  It would depend upon how much interactivity you want.  I would advise you pick a graphing application that is extensible or has an API - that suits your budget.  The better ones are (in my opinion) in the CAD domain, such as AutoCAD (£4k/seat), TurboCAD, VeCAD (£200/seat); and all have packages that allow you to resell their product within yours.